# Switch data model structure based upon property c#

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.1

I am using a client to call an API.  In the API - I want the model to populate from the request body - but I want the model to be structured differently depending upon the name of a single property.  Basically I want to create something like a switch/case scenario with a data model, but am unsure how to implement this. The last model contains pseudo code based upon what I want to acheive (obviously generic type won't work in the way I described, but I feel it completes my example).  Here's my example:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost("customer", Name = "Submit Customer")]
public IActionResult ActivateCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
{
    //Do something with the Customer object.
    return Ok();
}
```

**Customer Model:**

```
public class Customer
 {
     public CustomerInfo customerInfo { get; set; }
     public SponserInfo sponserInfo { get; set; }
 }
```

**CustomerInfo:**

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    //etc.
}
```

**SponserA:**

```
public class SponserA
{
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**SponserB:**

```
public class SponserB
{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

**SponserInfo: (pseudo-code of what I would like)**

```
public class SponserInfo
{
    public string SponserName { get; set; }
    public T SponserInfo { get; set; }

    switch(this.SponserName)
    {
        case "Sponser A's Name":
            T = SponserA;
            break;
        case "Sponser B's Name":
            T = SponserB;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use either an interface or a base class as the "base" for the classes you want to return.  Change your `T` in your pseudo-code to that interface or base class.  In the cases of your switch, construct the right type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one extensible way.

An attribute maps the sponsor name to the subclass, so SponsorInfo doesn't have to be aware of all subclasses.

It uses an abstract base class (`Sponsor`) for all Sponsor types (as also recommended by @Flydog57).

When `SponsorInfo.SponsorName` is assigned, the instance of a subclass of this is created (so you have to assign `SponsorName` first).

You can adjust that depending on how you actually map the properties from your model.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;


/// <summary>
/// Attribute to indicate the name mapped to a <see cref="Sponsor"/> subclass.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class SponsorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SponsorAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The value that <see cref="SponserInfo.SponserName"/> must match for the attribute class to be used.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Sponsor
{
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[Sponsor("Sponser A's Name")]
public class SponsorA : Sponsor
{
}

[Sponsor("Sponser B's Name")]
public class SponsorB : Sponsor
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

// More subclasses can be added.

public class SponsorInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Sponsor name.
    /// Changing this sets <see cref="Sponsor"/> to a new instance of the corresponding class.
    /// </summary>
    public string SponsorName
    {
        get { return _sponsorName; }
        set
        {
            if (_sponsorName != value)
            {
                _sponsorName = value;

                // Find a Sponsor subclass with a SponsorAttribute.Name matching the given value:
                Type sponsorType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()   // you might want to also scan other assemblies
                    .Where(t =>
                        t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Sponsor))
                        && (t.GetCustomAttribute<SponsorAttribute>()?.Name?.Equals(_sponsorName) ?? false)
                    ).FirstOrDefault();   // null if none is found

                if (sponsorType == null)
                    Sponsor = null;     // no matching class
                else
                    Sponsor = (Sponsor)Activator.CreateInstance(sponsorType);  // new instance of the matching class
            }
        }
    }
    private string _sponsorName;

    public Sponsor Sponsor { get; set; }   // renamed from "SponsorInfo" because that's the name of this class
}
```

---

This is dual licensed as public domain (CC0) and the normal licensing of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Works like a charm - with this implementation there is no need to manually parse the JSON request.  Thanks to @Flydog57 as well for the input.  I've marked this as the accepted answer due to it performing exactly as requested.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
public abstract class SponsorInfo
{
    public string SponserName { get; set; }

    protected SponsorInfo(string sponserName)
    {
        SponserName = sponserName;
    }
}

public class SponsorA : SponsorInfo
{
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public SponsorA(string sponserName, int referenceId, string password) 
        : base(sponserName)
    {
        ReferenceId = referenceId;
        Password = password;
    }
}

public class SponsorB : SponsorInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public SponsorB(string sponsorName, string userName, string relation, string department) 
        : base(sponsorName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Relation = relation;
        Department = department;
    }
}
```

Then, leave your Customer class alone (but fix the typo):

```
public class Customer
{
    public CustomerInfo customerInfo { get; set; }
    public SponsorInfo sponsorInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller, add the switch statement and construct either a `SponsorA` or a `SponsorB` depending on what the data looks like.  Either of those is a SponsorInfo, so you can attach it as the `sponsorInfo` in your `Customer` object.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and example.  This is definitely what I'm looking for, but I have to find a way to capture the request body values and construct the ```SponsorInfo``` upon receiving the request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a model called `Sponsor` that has all your fields, and then if `ReferenceId` is null, you'll know which kind of sponsor it is?

```
public class SponsorInfo 
{
    public int? ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("customer", Name = "Submit Customer")]
public IActionResult ActivateCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
{
    //Do something with the Customer object.
    if (customer.sponsorInfo.ReferenceId == null || !customer.sponsorInfo.ReferenceId.HasValue)
    {
        //is SponsorB
    }
    else
    {
        //is SponsorA
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  My example was just an example - the real project has hundreds of "sponsor" classes - which is why I want a way to populate the model (from request body) based upon the name.  I was trying to avoid cramming all properties from all sponsors into a giant model.  Still - thank you for your response.

Comment: In that case, you may have some luck making the parameter a string, and then using JSON.NET to deserialize it once inside the method.

Comment: Thank you @codeMonkey!  Your comment on controller parameter + @FlyDog57's example = my answer :-)